# modify string to array, regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I get a String like this:

```
'1': '-' '10': CustomerA; 79,00 EUR/Std '11': CustomerB; 155,00 EUR/Std '12': CustomerC; 75,00 EUR/Std '13': CustomerD; 50,00 EUR/Std '2': CustomerA; 000 EUR/Std '3': CustomerA; 000 EUR/Std '4': CustomerA; 120,00 EUR/Std '5': Customer; 75,00 EUR/Std
```

Better view:

```
'1': '-'
'10': CustomerA; 79,00 EUR/Std
'11': CustomerB;  155,00 EUR/Std
'12': CustomerC; 75,00 EUR/Std
'13': CustomerD; 50,00 EUR/Std
'2': CustomerA; 000 EUR/Std
```

And try to get an array with this datas:

```
array(
'key' => <CustomerName>; <Price> EUR/Std,
...);
```

I had already tried this, but it does only work if there are word wraps..

```
$string = preg_split('[0-9+]', $string);
$pattern = "~^'(\d+)':\s+(.+)$~mx";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern without splitting string:

```
~
'\d+':      # one-or-more digits wrapped by single quotes, followed by colon
\s+         # one-or-more spaces
([^']+)     # group 1: one-or-more not-single quote char
;           # semicolon
\s+         # one-or-more spaces
(.+?)       # group 2: one-or-more character, ungreedy option
\s+         # one-or-more spaces
(EUR/\w+)   # group 3: literally “EUR/” followed by one-or-more word chars
~x
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB9cK5/1)**</kbd>

The groups are:

1. Customer
2. Price
3. Currency

In group 1 I use any not-quote char to avoid 1st empty `'1:'` match.

---

Variants:

1. If you have more Currency variants, replace `(EUR/\w+)` with `(\w+/\w+)`
2. If the `/Std` is optional, replace `(EUR/\w+)` with `(EUR(/\w+)?)` or `(\w+(/\w+)?)`

Comment: What if price is not always `EUR/std`?

Comment: @Phate01  I have intended all in EUR (as the example provided). But I will add a variant. Thank you.

Comment: I know but very often there are always some other case we might not know

Comment: @Phate01 Yup. But this is right for any question. We have to suppose that the provided sample is representative of real code... However, I well know that often it is not so. OP question seems sufficiently accurate (He provide also 000 example)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the competent answer. I modify your `$pattern` a litl bit to this:

```
~'(\d+)+':([^']+;\s+.+?)\s+(EUR/\w+)~x
```

I just need the Id and the customer Company with the price. Then i use a `explode` function.

Comment: Are you sure about this way? You can already have separated values: why double the job?

Comment: I need foreach record 3 values: id, name of company and float price. EUR/Std is not necessary.